# comapre two dataframe and add particular column value based on match

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframe like this:

DF1

```
product_name        cost  Account  Acc_no
prod1               200   NA-STG   1264509
prod2               500   NA-STG   1264509
prod3               800   NA-STG   1264509
prod5               300   NA-STG   1264509
prod3               804   NA-DEV   1264345
prod4               511   NA-DEV   1264345
prod5               308   NA-DEV   1264345
```

df2:

```
product_name        active_subscription distributed_cost  account_alias
prod1                   20              1299.498484       NA-STG
prod2                   50              3248.746211       NA-STG
prod3                   80              5197.993937       NA-STG
prod4                   80              97.993937         NA-STG
prod4                   32              1000              NA-DEV
```

I want add the distributed_cost from df2 into df1 based account.If any product in df2(ex:prod4 is missing in df1) is missing in df1 then corresponding records has to be added in df1.So the output I want is:

```
product_name        cost          Account
prod1               1499.498484   NA-STG
prod2               3748.746211   NA-STG
prod3               5997.993937   NA-STG
prod4               97.993937     NA-STG
prod5               300           NA-STG
prod3               804           NA-DEV
prod4               1511          NA-DEV
prod5               308           NA-DEV
```

How can I implement this in efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pd.concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with a [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to get your result, as below:

```
pd.concat([
     df1.drop('Acc_no',axis=1),
     (df2.drop('active_subscription',axis=1)).rename({'distributed_cost':'cost','account_alias':'Account'},axis=1)]) \
    .groupby(['product_name','Account'])['cost'].sum() \
    .reset_index() \
    .sort_values(['Account','product_name'],ascending=[False,True]
)
```

which prints:

```
  product_name Account         cost
0        prod1  NA-STG  1499.498484
1        prod2  NA-STG  3748.746211
3        prod3  NA-STG  5997.993937
5        prod4  NA-STG    97.993937
7        prod5  NA-STG   300.000000
2        prod3  NA-DEV   804.000000
4        prod4  NA-DEV  1511.000000
6        prod5  NA-DEV   308.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Do below steps to achieve it:

1. Perform outer `merge` on your dataframes using **product_names** and **account** respective columns in both DFs.
2. Fill the mising values in **account** column (Since some values are in **DF2** but not in **DF1**).
3. Add the **cost** and **distributed_cost** values.
4. Finally select the columns you want to get your final dataframe.

**Code:**

```
df = df1.merge(df2, right_on=['product_name','account_alias'], left_on=['product_name','Account'], how='outer')
df['Account'] = df['Account'].fillna(df['account_alias'])
df['cost'] = df['cost'].fillna(0) + df['distributed_cost'].fillna(0)
df = df.loc[:, ['product_name','cost', 'Account']]
```

**Output**:

```
>>> df.sort_values(['Account', 'product_name'], ascending=[False,True])
  product_name         cost Account
0        prod1  1499.498484  NA-STG
1        prod2  3748.746211  NA-STG
2        prod3  5997.993937  NA-STG
7        prod4    97.993937  NA-STG
3        prod5   300.000000  NA-STG
4        prod3   804.000000  NA-DEV
5        prod4  1511.000000  NA-DEV
6        prod5   308.000000  NA-DEV
```